# How to clear a field after submitting a form and display the form values after the page reloads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### CODE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Form.css';

class Form extends Component {

    state = {
        firstName: '',
        phoneNo: '',
        showForm: false
    }

    displayFormHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedName = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            firstName: updatedName,
        });
        
    }

    displayPhoneNoHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedPhoneNo = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ phoneNo: updatedPhoneNo });
    }

    handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            showForm: true
        });

        

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.Form}>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" 
                        className={classes.inputArea}
                        name="firstName"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        onChange={this.displayFormHandler}
                        value={this.state.firstName} />
                    <label>PhoneNo:</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className={classes.inputArea}
                        placeholder="PhoneNo"
                        name="phoneNo"
                        onChange={this.displayPhoneNoHandler}
                        value={this.state.phoneNo} />
                    <button type="submit" className={classes.Button}
                        clicked={this.handleFormSubmit}  >Submit</button>
                    <div className={classes.UserInfo}>
                        {this.state.showForm && <p>UserName: {this.state.firstName}</p>}
                        {this.state.showForm && <p>UserName: {this.state.phoneNo}</p>}


                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

The code is mentioned above.

I created a form in React.JS. It echoes back the data from the form response; however, the data suddenly disappears after refreshing the page. I would like to find a suitable method that would allow me to store the user's response to the form and display it (even after the page has been refreshed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display submitted info after refresh the page in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151891/how-to-display-submitted-info-after-refresh-the-page-in-react-js)

Comment: Hi @Raj if any of the answers here has helped you solve your issue please mark the one that has helped you the most as the correct answer. If not, please add a comment to see what else can be done by the community.

Comment: Hi @chavez, sure ill mark correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To display form data even after the user has reloaded the page you could use the browsers local storage and at the start of each session just read the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display form data after page reload you need to store them somewhere best place would use browser [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API. To clear form data after submit is easy just add your two input state values to `setState` method that you already have in your submit method.

Firstly we will try to get data from `localStorage` in `constructor` of the component class. If `localStorage` is not empty we set its value as default component state. Here is a code example.

```
constructor() {
   const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData')); // get data from localStorage and parse it.
   if (data !== null) { // Check if data even exists
     this.state = { 
       firstName: data.firstName,
       phoneNo: data.phoneNo,
       showForm: false
     }; // set default React state.
   }
}
```

Secondly set the data after form submit. Here is another code example.

```
handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {firstName, phoneNo} = this.state;
        localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify({ firstName, phoneNo })); // parse the data and save it.
        this.setState({
            firstName: '',
            phoneNo: '',
            showForm: true
        }); // Clear the form data
    }
```